# Using awk, find or grep for svn export

Tags: awk, grep, find, subversion

I am trying to download only some files with the name "battery", using `svn export`:

```
svn export https://github.com/zayronxio/Mojave-CT/trunk/panel/24 | awk "battery"
svn export https://github.com/zayronxio/Mojave-CT/trunk/panel/24 | find . -iname "battery"
svn export https://github.com/zayronxio/Mojave-CT/trunk/panel/24 | grep -l "battery"
```

But these commands download all unnecessary files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can list files on remote repository with `ls` (check `svn help ls`) and can it filter with `grep`.

I filter with `sed` because make some modification (insert the repository URL before the file name). With `xargs` pass the file list to `svn export`.

```
svn ls "https://github.com/zayronxio/Mojave-CT/trunk/panel/24" | \
  sed -n '/battery/ s,^,https://github.com/zayronxio/Mojave-CT/trunk/panel/24/,p' | \
  xargs -L1 svn export
```